# Apply two different Sklearn classifiers to two different subsets of the same data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a dataset that I need to run through a classification Pipeline. The dataset has 2 types of rows:

- **described:** `description` column POPULATED
- **non-desribed:** `description` column EMPTY

I want to apply one classifier targetting ONLY the described data, and another one for the non-described data.

I am currently doing so by separating the dataset, and then preprocessing and feeding the dataset with their corresponding classifier separately. What I want to accomplish is fitting this process into a Sklearn pipeline. It should be something like this:

```
classifierPipe = Pipeline([('preproc_described', DescPreprocessor),
                           ('preproc_non_described', NonDescPreprocessor),
                           ('clf_described', CLF1),
                           ('clf_described', CLF2)
                          ])

classifierPipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I was reviewing `StackingClassifier`, but according to the documentation, initial estimators are applied to all the rows in the dataset.

How can I create such a pipeline where each classifier targets a specific subset of the whole dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create two different datasets and use one classifier on each. A simple code like below should be sufficient

```html
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_cvs('csv_name.csv')

#drop each column in the resp dataset
for_clf_1 = df.drop(['described'],axis = 1)
for_clf_2 = df.drop(['not described'], axis =1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That solution is the one that I am currently doing, and it works as you suggested. I am researching if there is a way to do this by using sklearn pipelines, to be able to perform everything by using a single item, with a single fit & predict method